# Why does my double loop print out a weird value

Tags: python, loops

Edit: I'm on mobile and it didn't format correctly. This is my first time with stack overflow

I am super new to programming and don't even know how to phrase and search the question I am trying to have answered

When I run this:

```
Magicians = ['kory', 'bob', 'jamie', 'cody']
for Magicians in Magicians:
    print(Magicians)
for Magicians in Magicians:
    print(Magicians)
```

I get this:
    kory
    bob
    jamie
    cody
    c
    o
    d
    y

Can someone please help me understand? I am reading python crash course by Eric matthes and it doesn't cover anything about this and I can't figure it out

Thank you

Comment: You probably want `for Magician in Magicians`.

Comment: You have a problem in naming your variables. You have named every variable be `Magicians`. Your two for loops are just identical. The only difference is initial loop is looping over the list while the second loop is looping over the last element of list which is `'cody'`. This is really a bad practice

Comment: You are using the same name for the variables. The first loop works as expected because the array items are listed prior to the loop execution and then each value is assigned to the same variable name. When the first loop finishes, it leaves Magicians set to "cody", hence the second execution gives only the letters for that string.

Comment: What is your intention? There are already a bunch of responses but what are you expecting?

Comment: I did it on purpose so I could see if it brought up an error and when it showed the result I was really confused, and still am, why doesn't it show k o r y since that's the first item in the list? I'm just confused why it broke up Cody into 4 letters.

Comment: Why does the second loop go to the last item in the list?

Comment: The second loop goes to the last loop because you are writing over the original list by reusing the same variable name `Magicians`. The last value stored in the `for` loop is the last item and since it is a string, it will be iterated one character at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop says to split `Magicians` into items, so the first iteration would be "kory". Your next loop (which only runs for the last value "cody" because it is not nested) is told to further split this into items. It does this by taking the string "cody" and splitting it into letters. Each letter is then printed!

You can try the following:

```
Magicians = ['kory', 'bob', 'jamie', 'cody']
for Magician in Magicians:
    print(Magician)
    for letter in Magician:
        print(letter)
```

This will print "kory k o r y bob b o b jamie j a m i e cody c o d y" and I think exemplifies essentially what you are trying to do.

Comment: Did you mean `print(Magician)`?

Comment: @ferrix yeah I fixed it just before you commented!

Answer (score 0):

It prints `c o d y` because at the last loop, you used the variable `Magicians` as the iteration variable. Thus, `Magicians` after the first loop equals to the string `"cody"`. In python, you can iterate a string as a list, this is why in the second loop, you get the letters of `"cody"`.

```
Magicians = ['kory', 'bob', 'jamie', 'cody']
for Magicians in Magicians:
    print(Magicians)
# Prints: kory   bob  jaime  cody
#Now Magicians = 'cody'
for Magicians in Magicians:
    print(Magicians)
#Prints: c o d y
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension might help you to understand how loop works

This will spit out all the characters for each machigian in the list `Magicians`

```
Magicians = ['kory', 'bob', 'jamie', 'cody']
[[char for char in magician] for magician in Magicians]
```

Output:

```
[['k', 'o', 'r', 'y'],
 ['b', 'o', 'b'],
 ['j', 'a', 'm', 'i', 'e'],
 ['c', 'o', 'd', 'y']]
```